# Can two .NET apps on same Windows 10 computer communicate by USB with each other without a USB loopback cable?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, usb

So, the 1st app is the USB host, and the 2nd app simulates a USB device.

After that, I would then like to test using a USB loopback cable, which it seems needs a USB bridge -- sometimes called a USB to USB adapter.

Next, I'll test same app running on two computers.

And, ultimately I need to test communication between GUI .NET app on Windows 10 (the USB host) with USB-2 connection to an embedded ARM (the USB device).  And, the embedded is not avail yet.

Comment: So your question seems to be "Can I mock a USB device"? Somewhat too broad.

Comment: I added clarification.